# Problem with finding the inverse of a matrix in python

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to calculate the inverse of a Jacobian matrix. I calculated the Jacobian using sympy. But, now when I try to inv the matrix, I am getting an error, which I don't understand. It would be great if anyone could help me

```
import numpy as py
from numpy.linalg import inv
from sympy import Matrix
import warnings

def f1(y1, y2, y3, y1_old, dt):
    return y1_old + (-0.04*y1 + 10**4*y2*y3)*dt

def f2(y1, y2, y3, y2_old, dt):
    return y2_old + (0.04*y1 - 10**4*y2*y3 - (3.10**7)*(y2**2))*dt

def f3(y1, y2, y3, y3_old, dt):
    return y3_old + ((3.10**7)*(y2**2))*dt

def j(y1,y2,y3):
    a = Matrix(('-0.04*y1 + 10**4*y2*y3','0.04*y1 - 10**4*y2*y3 - (3.10**7)* 
    (y2**2)','(3.10^7)*(y2**2)')).jacobian(('y1', 'y2', 'y3'))
    a = str(a)
    a = eval(a)
    return a

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

y_old = py.zeros((3,1))
y_old[0] = 1

#Guess values for the implicit variable
y_guess = 2*py.ones((3,1))

#New values - assumed initially
y_new = py.ones((3,1))

F = py.copy(y_new)

start_time = 0
end_time = 10
dt = 0.01
nt = py.arange(start_time,end_time,dt)

error = 9e9
tol = 1e-10
alpha = 0.8
#for i in range(0,len(nt)):

#while error>tol:

jac = j(y_guess[0],y_guess[1],y_guess[2])

F[0] = f1(y_guess[0],y_guess[1],y_guess[2], y_old[0], dt)
F[1] = f2(y_guess[0],y_guess[1],y_guess[2], y_old[1], dt)
F[2] = f3(y_guess[0],y_guess[1],y_guess[2], y_old[2], dt)

j = inv(jac)#error
```

Here is the error I am getting:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCskF.png)

Comment: Does [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452792/cannot-cast-array-data-from-dtypeo-to-dtypefloat64) help?

Comment: Don't use eval cause could be inefficient in these cases. `sympy` can compute also non-symbolic math so the `j` function culd also be: `def j(y1, y2, y3): return Matrix((-0.04*y1 + 10**4*y2*y3, 0.04*y1 - 10**4*y2*y3 - (3.10**7)* 
    (y2**2), (3.10^7)*(y2**2))).jacobian((y1, y2, y3))` (removing strings from computation)

Comment: This works, but it wont calculate the derivative wrt numbers. That is, I cant substitute values in place of variables y1, y2 and y3.

Comment: For those of us who can't run your code, showing `jac` would be the polite thing to do.  I'm guessing it's object dtype, possibly containing sympy symbols.  or `ragged` (since you turned off warnings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of things wrong here. Firstly don't turn off warnings: they are there for a reason. The warning you should be seeing is:

```
sympy/matrices/repmatrix.py:102: SymPyDeprecationWarning: 

non-Expr objects in a Matrix has been deprecated since SymPy 1.9. Use
list of lists, TableForm or some other data structure instead. See
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/21497 for more info.

  deprecated_since_version="1.9"
```

That warning is seen because you set some elements of a SymPy matrix to be NumPy arrays so your matrix looks like

```
In [2]: jac
Out[2]: 
⎡-0.04     [20000.0]      [20000.0] ⎤
⎢                                   ⎥
⎢0.04   [-31005.0456444]  [-20000.0]⎥
⎢                                   ⎥
⎣  0    [11005.0456444]       0     ⎦
```

In future something like that will immediately raise an exception. The warning is a polite reminder that you should change your code or it won't work with a future version of SymPy.

Until you have a better understanding of what each of SymPy and NumPy can do I suggest just sticking to only one of them and not trying to mix them together.

You have numbers like `3.10^7` which I assume is supposed to be `30000000.0` but that should really be written as `3e7` or `3*10**7`.

The normal way to do this in SymPy is this:

```
In [9]: y1, y2, y3 = symbols('y1, y2, y3')

In [10]: a = Matrix([-0.04*y1 + 10**4*y2*y3, 0.04*y1 - 10**4*y2*y3 - 3e7*y2**2, 3e7*y2**2])

In [11]: a
Out[11]: 
⎡        -0.04⋅y₁ + 10000⋅y₂⋅y₃        ⎤
⎢                                      ⎥
⎢                       2              ⎥
⎢0.04⋅y₁ - 30000000.0⋅y₂  - 10000⋅y₂⋅y₃⎥
⎢                                      ⎥
⎢                         2            ⎥
⎣            30000000.0⋅y₂             ⎦

In [12]: jac = a.jacobian([y1, y2, y3])

In [13]: jac
Out[13]: 
⎡-0.04          10000⋅y₃           10000⋅y₂ ⎤
⎢                                           ⎥
⎢0.04   -60000000.0⋅y₂ - 10000⋅y₃  -10000⋅y₂⎥
⎢                                           ⎥
⎣  0          60000000.0⋅y₂            0    ⎦
```

Then if you want the inverse you can use the `jac.inv()` method so that SymPy can compute the inverse of the matrix. Alternatively you can substitute values for the symbols and then convert to a NumPy array and use NumPy's `inv` function.

Either way you have a problem here because the matrix is singular for all possible values of the symbols `y1`, `y2` and `y3`:

```
In [14]: jac.det()
Out[14]: 0

In [15]: jac.inv()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NonInvertibleMatrixError
```

It's easy enough to see that the rows sum to zero so the matrix does not have full rank.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of displaying the problem, without `sympy` pretty printing

```
In [5]: jac = j(y_guess[0],y_guess[1],y_guess[2])
In [6]: jac
Out[6]: 
Matrix([
[-0.04,        [20000.0],  [20000.0]],
[ 0.04, [-31005.0456444], [-20000.0]],
[    0,  [11005.0456444],          0]])
```

The `numpy` `inv` works with numeric arrays.  Due to the mix of lists and scalars in `jac`, the result is an object dtype array.

```
In [7]: np.array(jac)
Out[7]: 
array([[-0.0400000000000000, [20000.0], [20000.0]],
       [0.0400000000000000, [-31005.0456444], [-20000.0]],
       [0, [11005.0456444], 0]], dtype=object)

In [8]: np.linalg.inv(_)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-8-61bbaec16d5b>", line 1, in <module>
    np.linalg.inv(_)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in inv
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 545, in inv
    ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc inv
```

I don't know if you can clean up the `jac` formulation so it does not use the mix of scalars and lists.  In any case, it is clear that using a mix of a `sympy` and `numpy` is not for the novice, especially if he neglects to examine the intermediate variables.

Cleaning up the extra []:

```
In [14]: M = np.array([[-0.0400000000000000, 20000.0, 20000.0],
    ...:        [0.0400000000000000, -31005.0456444, -20000.0],
    ...:        [0, 11005.0456444, 0]])
    ...: 
    ...: 
In [15]: M
Out[15]: 
array([[-4.00000000e-02,  2.00000000e+04,  2.00000000e+04],
       [ 4.00000000e-02, -3.10050456e+04, -2.00000000e+04],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  1.10050456e+04,  0.00000000e+00]])
```

This does run, but with a different error:

```
In [16]: np.linalg.inv(M)
....
LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

`y_guess` is a (3,1) array, so evaluating `j` as you do passes (1,) arrays in:

```
In [17]: y_guess
Out[17]: 
array([[2.],
       [2.],
       [2.]])
```

If instead, we pass scalars to `j`, the resulting matrix does not have the extra bracketting:

```
In [18]: j(2,2,2)
Matrix([[-0.04*y1 + 10000*y2*y3], [0.04*y1 - 2751.2614111*y2**2 - 10000*y2*y3], [2751.2614111*y2**2]])
Matrix([[-0.0400000000000000, 10000*y3, 10000*y2], [0.0400000000000000, -5502.5228222*y2 - 10000*y3, -10000*y2], [0, 5502.5228222*y2, 0]])
Out[18]: 
Matrix([
[-0.04,          20000,  20000],
[ 0.04, -31005.0456444, -20000],
[    0,  11005.0456444,      0]])
```

Now it's possible to creates a numeric array that `np.linalg` can use

```
In [20]: np.array(j(2,2,2),float)
Out[20]: 
array([[-4.00000000e-02,  2.00000000e+04,  2.00000000e+04],
       [ 4.00000000e-02, -3.10050456e+04, -2.00000000e+04],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  1.10050456e+04,  0.00000000e+00]])
```